# Configuring Java applications

Tags: java, configuration

The applications that our company develops require extensive configuration. Config files are complex and they change often during the lifetime of the application. Our current approach is to externalize them. We store them at certain locations in the filesystem and expose their locations to applications through environment variables. Although this approach works, it adds unwanted complexity to application development itself. I would like to know if there are other ways of configuring an application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at centralized configuration services like [ZooKeeper](https://zookeeper.apache.org/), [Consul](https://www.consul.io/), [Doozerd](https://github.com/ha/doozerd) and alike. If you use Spring, they have [their own](https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/) centralized configuration system that might be of use to you.